# Как извлечь переменные из таблицы и поместить их в текущую область видимости?

Tags: lua

У меня есть таблица, в которой содержится множество различных классов. Мне хотелось бы использовать эти классы напрямую из модуля, который подключает эту таблицу, без обращения к родителям (`Window` вместо `app.gui.Window`).

Вот простейший пример того, что мне нужно:

```
t = {
  a = 1,
  b = 2,
  c = 3
}

function f(t)
  print(t.b) -- так работает
  print(b) -- как заставить работать так?
end

f(t)
```

**UPD:** Конечно, проще всего было бы решить задачу таким образом: `b = t.b`, но давайте условимся, что мне заранее не известны имена ключей из таблицы t (точнее, они-то мне конечно известны, но `a = t.a; b = t.b; c = t.c ... z = t.z` - это какой-то говнокод).

Вот такое решение мне только что пришло в голову:

```
function f(t)
  print(t.b) -- так работает
  for k, v in pairs(t) do _G[k] = v end
  print(b) -- и так работает!
end
```

...Но, как вы видите, оно затрагивает глобальную область видимости, а не локальную и это недопустимо! Мне нужен локальный аналог **_G**, какой-нибудь **_L**.

Есть идея создать такую переменную и прописать у неё в метаметодах `debug.getlocal` и `debug.setlocal`, правда я не особо разобрался в синтаксисе этих функций и в метаметодах пока ещё не силён, но буду пытаться.

Comment: `local Window=app.gui.Window` и далее использовать `Window` или даже без `local`

Comment: @MikeV. Ну да, это самое очевидное решение, но такой вариант мне не подходит. Список классов будет расширяться, я не знаю заранее все их имена. Хотелось бы просто извлечь из таблицы всё её содержимое.

Comment: @MikeV. Обновил вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробую предложить реализовать область видимости через модуль,
поместим код в файл `test.lua` :

```
module('test', package.seeall)
t = {   a = 1, b = 2,  c = 3 }

for k,v in pairs(t) do
      _M[k] = v -- вынимаем переменные из таблицы в область видимости модуля _M
end

print(t.b, b)  -- 2 2
```

в качестве примера, вызываем модуль и проверяем глобальную переменную `b`:

```
b = 4

local test = require "test"

print(test.t.b) -- 2
print(test.b)  -- 2  ( b в модуле )
print(b)        --  4   ( b глобальная )
```

2 метод с помощью метатаблицы и наследования:

```
local _M = {}   
setmetatable(_M, {__index = _G})
setfenv(1, _M)

t = { a = 1, b = 2, c = 3 }

for k,v in pairs(t) do
      _M[k] = v
end

print(t.b, b)  -- 2 2

return _M
```

если вызвать этот файл с помощью `require` результат будет тот же, недостаток - лишние накладные расходы по наследованию _G.

и 3 путь, можно задать область видимости с помощью только setenv, но тогда нужно явно вызывать функции через конструкцию типа `_G.pairs`, что не совсем красиво :

```
local _M = {}
local _G = _G
setfenv(1, _M)

t = {  a = 1,  b = 2,  c = 3 }

for k,v in  _G.pairs(t) do
      _M[k] = v
end

_G.print(t.b, b)  -- 2  2

return _M
```

Comment: Следует заметить, что с версии луа 5.2 `setfenv` более не используется.

Comment: @val да,  но обходные пути [есть](http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2011-05/msg00115.html), правда не проверял.

Comment: В данном случае обходной путь не нужен, достаточно заменить `setfenv(1, _M)` на `_ENV = _M`

Comment: @val тут согласен

Comment: @MikeV. Боюсь, что ни один вариант не работает так, как мне хотелось бы в идеальном виде, но похоже что тут ничего лучше не придумать. Спасибо большое!